# android google cloud messaging app not able to send messages and giving error in php

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

Friends, I am working on a simple android test app with the basic task to send a message from a php application server to device from gcm. I am able to register on gcm from the device and then i try to send the registration id to the web application. following are the main files associated with the app where I think something may needs to be rectified:

```
   Congfig.java

public interface Config {

    // used to share GCM regId with application server - using php app server
    static final String APP_SERVER_URL = "http://49.249.146.129/gcm/gcm.php?shareRegId=1";

    // GCM server using java
    // static final String APP_SERVER_URL =
    // "http://192.168.1.17:8080/GCM-App-Server/GCMNotification?shareRegId=1";

    // Google Project Number
    //static final String GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID = "512218038480";
    static final String GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID = "1190";
    static final String MESSAGE_KEY = "message";

}
```

This is the error that I am getting when i try to send a push message from the php file.

```
           Warning: file_get_contents(GCMRegId.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\gcm\gcm.php on line 37
Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) Server in PHP
  {"multicast_id":7821558258646259390,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

Kindly help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code, its work for me. Just pass the device id and message it will send a notification. Check it

```
function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message,
    );

    define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "API Key Here");

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

 $pushMessage = $name." was created meeting to you.";

            if(isset($gcmRegIds) && isset($pushMessage)) {
                $message = array('message' => $pushMessage, 'type' => 'Request', 'token' => $token);
                $pushStatus = $this->send_notification($gcmRegIds, $message);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

"*InvalidRegistration*" means Registration id that you sent is not registered. Check API key and registration id correctly. Check the formatting of the registration ID that you pass to the server. So basically you are making an error in sending the DeviceID received by the phone to the server.

You may check the part of Receive a downstream messaging here:         https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Here's a useful link regarding Registration Token: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register